# How to get only the user, the pid and the command run for a specific process? (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: linux, bash, ps

When I do `ps -ef|grep python` I get the following:

```
myusername  4492  2994  0 10:32 pts/0    00:00:01 /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/ipython manage.py runserver
root        6665     1  0 10:42 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d
myusername 14051 13497  0 11:28 pts/7    00:00:00 grep --color=auto python
```

How do I get only the **user** who is running the process, the **pid** and the **command** run for the process as in the following output instead?

```
myusername  4492 /home/myusername/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/ipython manage.py runserver
root        6665 /usr/bin/python /usr/lib/system-service/system-service-d
```

Comment: Does this work? `ps --fields="user pid command"`

Comment: Didn't try it. Found it on the net. Not near a Ubuntu machine now. Sorry. Will see later and let you know

Comment: Nope, I get ERROR: Unknown gnu long option. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess you are looking for the -o argument:

> -o format:
>
> user-defined format.
>   format is a single argument in the form of a
>   blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a
>   way to specify individual output columns. The
>   recognized keywords are described in the STANDARD
>   FORMAT SPECIFIERS section below. Headers may be renamed
>   (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o comm=Command) as desired.
>   If all column headers are empty (ps -o pid= -o comm=)
>   then the header line will not be output. Column width
>   will increase as needed for wide headers; this may be
>   used to widen up columns such as WCHAN
>   (ps -o pid,wchan=WIDE-WCHAN-COLUMN -o comm). Explicit
>   width control (ps opid,wchan:42,cmd) is offered too.
>   The behavior of ps -o pid=X,comm=Y varies with
>   personality; output may be one column named "X,comm=Y"
>   or two columns named "X" and "Y". Use multiple -o
>   options when in doubt. Use the PS_FORMAT environment
>   variable to specify a default as desired; DefSysV and
>   DefBSD are macros that may be used to choose the
>   default UNIX or BSD columns.

So the command you want would be (Ubuntu):

```
ps -o uid,pid,cmd -ef|grep python
```

under OpenSolaris the command is:

```
ps -o ruser,pid,comm -ef|grep python
```

Comment: Does that actually work for you? When I run that command I get `Warning: bad ps syntax, perhaps a bogus '-'? See http://procps.sf.net/faq.html`

Comment: Yes it works for me in ksh under OpenSolaris. The output is as you desire... Check the man pages for ps on your system `man ps`. Maybe the syntax is slightly different on your system.

Comment: But the OP is on bash and not on ksh

Comment: @pratnala: Sorry must have been an oversight on my side... Nonetheless I tested it as well with bash on my system and it works as well...

Comment: @Bentley4: I tested the command `ps -o ruser,pid,comm -ef` on Ubuntu 10.04 and had the same result as you. I then run `ps -o uid,pid,cmd -ef` and got the desired result. I hope it works for you as well.

Comment: Unfortunately when I run `ps -o uid,pid,cmd -ef|python` I get about a half a page of information for each process.

Comment: @Bentley4 If you just want the command and don't need additional information you can drop the -f argument and use the following command: `ps -o uid,pid,cmd -e|grep python`

Comment: Thank you!! `ps -o user,pid,cmd -e|grep python` was the exact command I was looking for. Everytime I do this command however I get `myusername  1219 grep --color=auto command`(with `command` being `python` in this case). Any idea how to get rid of it?

Comment: @Bentley4: `ps -o user,pid,cmd -e|grep '[p]ython'`

Answer (score 4):

The simplest would probably be:

```
$ ps o uid=,pid=,cmd= -C python
1000 26126 python
```

That way you get everything directly from `ps` and don't need to parse anything.

From the `ps` man page:

> -o format
>                 User-defined format.  format is a single argument in the form of a blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a way to specify individual output columns.  [...] Headers may be renamed (ps -o pid,ruser=RealUser -o comm=Command) as desired.  **If all column headers are empty (ps -o pid= -o comm=) then the header line will not be output.**

```
-C cmdlist
     Select by command name.  This selects the processes whose executable 
     name is given in cmdlist.
```

The `-C` option will work if you are running `python` interactively, not if python is running a script. In that case you should use `-C scriptname.py` instead.

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -eo user,pid,cmd | grep [p]ython
```

Example:

```
$ ps -eo user,pid,cmd | grep [p]ython
root      1056 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/networkd-dispatcher --run-startup-triggers
root      1735 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start
user     16613 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/system-config-printer/applet.py
```

Explanation:

- `-e` all processes
- `-o` user-defined format
- `user,pid,cmd` Show user, process ID, command columns

**Note:** if you use `-f` with `-o` as others have suggested, you may get errors. This is because both of these parameters control the output format, and only one of them should be used:

```
$ ps --help | grep -A 2 "output format"
*********** output format **********
-o,o user-defined  -f full
-j,j job control   s  signal
```

Answer (score 1):

My version of PS is different, so it might require some tweaking, but you can use cut (and possibly tr depending on what you are trying to achieve) - for example something like

```
ps ef | cut -c1-16,50-
```

Will provide the characters 1-16 and 50 onwards from each line of your ps statement.  (Your actual numbers will probably need a bit of massaging).

Another way to do it (but you will loose formatting) might be

```
ps ef | tr -s " " | cut -f1,2,8- -d" "
```

Which will compress the whitespace in the ps command, then take fields 1,2 and 8 onwards and display them.

Comment: For only one process I get a half page of information on a full screen with those commands. It's pretty unreadable, I'm 'massaging' the parameters but so far I haven't been able to get anything remotely of what I want.